# ASP.NET ReportViewer's nav toolbar doesn't show properly in Webkit browsers

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, rdlc, report-viewer2010

I am using ReportViewer in Visual Studio 2010. It renders fine in IE but not in Webkit (Chrome & Safari) browsers. The toolbar elements display in separate lines, as shown in the image.  Is there a way to fix this without adding custom Javascript for styling?

Webkit (bad):

[image]

---

IE (good):

[image]

Comment: I'd check your CSS. Are you using a reset style sheet or something? Looks to me like it's display: block. I've got it running just fine in webkit browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've used the ReportViewer control in VS 2010 extensively with Google Chrome and other WebKit browsers fine.

The problem you are describing was common in the older versions of the reportviewer control, see here for a fix:

http://www.mazsoft.com/blog/post/2009/08/13/ReportViewer-control-toolbar-in-Google-Chrome-browser.aspx

But it is most likely a stray bit of CSS that is effecting the styling of the reportviewer control.

Comment: Changing to display: inline-block was very helpful.